# Change filter binding mode in Blazor Bootstrap Grid (https://demos.blazorbootstrap.com/grid)

Tags: blazor, grid, filtering

I would like to change the binding from oninput to onchange in Blazor Bootstrap Grid filter, is that possible ?

Problem is that the way its currently made on Blazor Bootstrap website , filter trigers on every input which is a lot for server and it can't handle it, so I would like to have it onchange - so when the focus is lost trigger the filtering. (Server side filtering)

Comment: It would help to know which Blazor Bootstrap Grid you are using?  Is it this one?   - https://docs.blazorbootstrap.com/components/grid.  Also see this on how to ask a question on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask